# Domain & Active Directory Migration

Tags: active-directory, domain

We just acquired a very small company, what is the best and easiest way to integrate a small domain to our own domain?

Answer (score 3):

If all they have is a small domain, migrate it into your existing domain. Microsoft provides a tool just for this purpose, the appropriately named Active Directory Migration Tool (ADMT).

Read more about it here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc974332(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score -2):

Don't.

You could join their domain to your forest but it's not worth it. If you've already been through the process of determining what resources and users need to be shared between the two organisations, you can do so through trust/federation. Joining one domain to another forest is usually a completely unnecessary step, with a lot of headache and is irreversible.

Comment: Why would you suggest to not migrate users into a single domain? One huge reason companies combine is to remove administrative overhead, part of which is managing directory services.

Comment: It's not even kind of "completely unnecessary"....